# Gitlab maven deploy to package registry

Tags: maven, gitlab

I am trying out gitlab and it looks very promosing. I have run into a huge problem and it seams as if nobody on the entire Internet has even a clue how to solve this.

I have added a project which is a maven project (There is only a pom.xml) and I want to deploy this to the package registry. If I do this from my home computer it is simple. I just add a deploy token to my settings.xml and do a `mvn deploy`.

I want to do a maven deploy to the package registry on each build so when I commit and push my code it needs to build. The thing is, how can I pass on the Deploy token to the pipeline? So in short I want to auto deploy a maven library/dependency so that other projects can use that dependency. This is how it should work however this is completly undocumented how to do it in gitlab and it almost seams as if nobody on this planet does it this way.

So in short, how can I deploy a maven project to the project/group package registry?

Answer (score 6):

Actually there is a pretty good explanation within the [gitlab documentation](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/maven_repository/#create-maven-packages-with-gitlab-cicd).

I will shortly outline this process, but in the end it is just a copy from the documentation, but the link can change, or it can be moved. So people in the future will find it as this answer.

As you can see in the explanation below, you can simply provide a settings.xml for maven with the `-s <file>` flag. Which allows you to store the basic settings.xml within you actual project.

1. Create a `ci_settings.xml` file that serves as Maven’s settings.xml file.
2. Add the server section with the same ID you defined in your `pom.xml` file. For example, use gitlab-maven as the ID:

   ```
    <settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.1.0.xsd">
      <servers>
        <server>
          <id>gitlab-maven</id>
          <configuration>
            <httpHeaders>
              <property>
                <name>Job-Token</name>
                <value>${env.CI_JOB_TOKEN}</value>
              </property>
            </httpHeaders>
          </configuration>
        </server>
      </servers>
    </settings>
   ```
3. Make sure your `pom.xml` file includes the following. You can either let Maven use the CI environment variables, as shown in this example, or you can hard code your server’s hostname and project’s ID.

   ```
    <repositories>
      <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>${env.CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
      </repository>
    </repositories>
    <distributionManagement>
      <repository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>${env.CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
      </repository>
      <snapshotRepository>
        <id>gitlab-maven</id>
        <url>${env.CI_SERVER_URL}/api/v4/projects/${env.CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/maven</url>
      </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
   ```
4. Add a deploy job to your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file:

   ```
    deploy:
      image: maven:3.6-jdk-11
      script:
        - 'mvn deploy -s ci_settings.xml'
   ```
5. Push those files to your repository.

Again i want to highlight that is the content of the actual documentation, and i just added it here for completeness (i am not a copy cat and do not want to get recognition of other peoples work! ;) )